# Cannot insert values into table 2 using prepared statement

Tags: php

I have two tables, called `items` and `posts`. The primary key **item_id** in the table one is the **foreign key** in the table two, using `INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL`. The table one stores the `item_id` (UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT), user id and the title of the post. The table two stores the following info: `item_id, user_id, message,` and `posted_on`

I do the validation for the new item id before running the query to make sure that **there is a new post** before any query is run:

```
// Validate item ID ($itemid), which may not be present:
if (isset($_POST['itemid']) && filter_var($_POST['itemid'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('min_range' => 1)) ) {
    $itemid = $_POST['itemid'];
} else {
    $itemid = FALSE;
}
```

After that, I make the `INSERT INTO` query using prepared statement for the table 2 like this:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO tablename2 (item_id, user_id, message, posted_on) VALUES (?,?,?, UTC_TIMESTAMP())";

//Prepare the statement
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($q);

//Bind the parameters
$stmt->bind_param('iis', $item_id, $user_id, $message);

//Assign values to variables
$item_id = (int)$_POST['itemid'];
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];// The user_id value would normally come from the session.
$message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);

//Execute the statement
$stmt->execute();

if ($mysqli->affected_rows == 1) {//
echo '<p>Your post has been entered.</p>';
} else {
echo '<p>Your post could not be handled due to a system error.</p>';
echo '<p>' . $stmt->error . '</p>';
}

// Close the statement:
$stmt->close();
```

Everything goes well, except that the `item_id`, which is inserted into the table2, appears to be 0 all the time, but not the same integer as it **should be** in the table 1 (`Primary - Foreign' keys relationship b/w the two tables`).

What did I do wrongly? can you help? Thanks.

Comment: check the `(int)$_POST['itemid']`  value before inserting into table

Comment: try var_dump(htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error))

Comment: I tried echoing `echo var_dump($item_id)."<br>";`, it returned `bool(false). . Then I tried `echo var_dump(htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));`, it returned `string(0) "" `. Can you help to correct it?

Comment: I found out the solution for it now: `$item_id = $itemid; //Assign values to variables`